# Misunderstanding With Basic One-To-One Set Theory

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> True or False: A function $f:A\to B$ is one-to-one iff for every $a \in A$ there exists exactly one $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

I answered this statement as being true, using the logic that a function must map every element of $A$, and additionally a one-to-one function forbids the mapping of more than one element of $A$ to the same value. Therefore, there must be a single value in $B$ for every element of $A$, which is just a restatement of the question. However, the statement is actually false, and no explanation is provided. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The quoted definition is a function.  It allows mapping of multiple $a$s to the same $b$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given true false question is actually just the condition for $f$ to be a well defined function---for every input, there is a unique output.

In order for $f$ to be one-to-one (injective), there needs to a unique *input* for each possible output. In the language of the question, it would need to be phrased as:

> A function $f: A \to B$ is one-to-one iff for every $b \in f(A) \subset B$ there exists exactly one $a \in A$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

Note that this agrees with the more common definition of:

> $f: A \to B$ is one-to-one if for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$ if $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ then $a_1 = a_2$.